# How do I fix access denied exceptions while using ESIntegTestCase?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to create a test case by extending ESIntegTestCase. I have a class that extends ElasticsearchTemplate and accepts a Client in the constructor. I figured I could use the client() method provided by ESIntegTestCase to pass in a client to my ElasticsearchTemplate. I am getting an access denied for java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission. It appears to be coming from Spring Data Elasticsearch. Any ideas?

Better yet, has anyone successfully performed a test using both ESIntegTestCase and Spring DI?

Comment: For now just added -Dtest.security.manager=false to the test.